# Нарисовать Землю с помощью OpenGL

Tags: qt, opengl, карты

Рисую с помощью OpenGL в Qt плоскую и 3Д Землю. На данный момент в качестве текстуры используется растровое изображение. Хочется, чтобы была возможность увеличивать карту с детализацией изображения.
С чего начать? Может какие-то статьи или книги есть на подобную тему? Сама в интернете ничего не нашла.

Answer (score 11):

Хранить географические карты в растре? Вы серьезно?

Начать нужно с того что:

1. Где-то достать растровую плоскую физическую карту мира
2. [Сконвертировать её в нормализованную 8 битную карту высот.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heightmap#/media/File:Srtm_ramp2.world.21600x10800.jpg) (уже кто-то сделал)
3. C помощью [displacement mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_mapping) получить полигональную сетку из растровой карты высот.
4. Спроецировать полученную сетку на сферу с помощью функции обратной, той что использовалась при развертке сферы в карту. (Картографические проекции достаточно сложны, однако по ним есть много информации)
5. В конце в качестве diffuse map использовать оригинальную карту. Также можно еще взять случайную [карту нормалей](https://web.archive.org/web/20140707085543/http://unigine.com/articles/131016-procedural-content-generation2/full/moss_normal_map.jpg) и добавить немного [bump mappingа](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_mapping) в получившийся ландшафт.

В результате может-быть получится более менее сносная картинка, которую можно нормально скалировать, вращать, бомбить трехмерными ядерными ракетами, заселять виртуальными горожанами, насылать нашествие инопланетян и.т.д. и.т.п.

[Вот еще годная статья по поводу сравнения методов рельефного текстурирования.](http://sirkan.iit.bme.hu/%7Eszirmay/egdisfinal3.pdf)

Также есть много софта для получения сетки рельефа напрямую из карты высот. Нарпимер всем известный [Terragen.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terragen)

С ним генерация картинок вроде такой становится тривиальной задачей вообще не требующей значительных художественных навыков:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И еще подборка статей про алгоритмическую генерацию рельефа местности:

[Как это делают в NVIDIA](https://web.archive.org/web/20161125183621/http://http.developer.nvidia.com:80/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch01.html)

[Фрактальная генерация](https://web.archive.org/web/20170812230846/http://www.gameprogrammer.com/fractal.html#diamond)

[Получение своих континетов для новичков](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/%7Eamitp/game-programming/polygon-map-generation/)

[Хороший пример генерации через WebGL размером всего в 130 строчек JS](https://demos.playfuljs.com/terrain/)

[Обзорная презентация. Мало формул, много примеров и названий технологий](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/%7Esugih/courses/eecs494/fall06/lectures/workshop-terrain.pdf)

Также имеет смысл ознакомится с различными [методами генерации градиентных шумов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D1%83%D0%BC_%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0), чтобы с помощью них получить свою случайную карту нормалей/высот и сделать ландшафт еще более реалистичным.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно детализировать текстуру то используй [MIP mapping](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIP-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)